# How can "exit" mean "continue"?

Tags: usability, buttons, icons

When you press <kbd>Exit</kbd> button on remote controller while using [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/), this player won't stop playback. It will exit to one of the menu pages that you've been browsing before playback, but [will continue playing movie in so-called "mini-player" in the background](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249789/20449).

This is a core functionality. It seems you [cannot turn it off or disable](https://kodi.wiki/view/Settings/Player/Videos) it using [configuration](https://kodi.wiki/view/Settings/Player).

What am I missing here? How can "exit" mean "continue"?

Comment: Exit full screen??

Comment: It's a misconception of the context. That's why descriptive labels are so important. Always add context to button actions unless the context is unmistakably clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is similar to a feature in YT where trying to leave the main screen playing the video causes a minimized window to continue playing while you exit to a home screen. It seems like this is some way to increase the 'engagement rate' of a user, whether it is really what the user wants to do or not.

Sadly, I don't think this is in line with best practice when it comes to meeting the user's expectations on actions taken, but it seems to be consistent with a lot of the design and implementation practices at the moment when it is about metrics and increasing them regardless of what the actual user experience is.